# Quartz scheduler job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have tried to make a scheduler job using quartz library. I have added the  quartz-all-xxx.jar file but it's showing me error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<init>(StdSchedulerFactory.java:298)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1516)
    at Main.Schedular.main(Schedular.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

so is there any other jar file I have to add ???

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on this [Maven repository page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.6) the quartz library has a dependency to `org.slf4j`.
Given your version of quartz, add the proper dependency version to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add SLF4J-API. Or, you know, use maven or something…

Edit: and probably some implementation.